# XPath expression that matches the bgcolor attribute of a TR element

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

Working with HtmlAgilityPack against table rows that have been generated without `name` or `id`. Instead, i need to select based on the value contained in the row's bgcolor attribute:

I understand that XPath will return all rows where the `name` attribute = `display`:

```
foreach(HtmlNode cell in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//tr[@name='display']/td")
```

Given the code snippet below, what expression will select all  elements when the row's `bgcolor ="#FFFFFF"`>?

I've tried: `SelectNodes(//tr[@bgcolor='#FFFFFF']/td")`

```
> <tr bgcolor="#EAF2FA">
>     <td colspan="2">
>         <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;"><strong>Name</strong></font>
>     </td> </tr> <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
>     <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
>     <td>
>         <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;">Steve</font>
>     </td> </tr>
```

thx

Comment: the xpath matches for me just fine. and i see no reason why it shouldn't work. can you show a bit more of the code?

Comment: I find that my code _does match when I working with a fully formed HTML document. Thanks for pointing out that the direction I was working _was correct.

Answer (score 0):

bgcolor is weird, I find that using a contains will fix the problem.

This will work...

```
SelectNodes(//*//tr[contains(@bgcolor, 'FFFFFF')]/td")
```